# Angular Material updates dynamically added elements' style after leaving any elements

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an annoying issue with Angular and Angular Material. I couldn't find any question similar to this for answer.
Scenario:
I am populating multiple elements inside a form using an array object. I have multiple arrays
By adding new item to the array I am expecting to have new instances of the elements.
This part happens meaning all elements are added to the page but the newly appeared elements have no Material styling, 
styles will apply when I click on any element in form and leave it. 
(meaning after blur of any element in the form the newly added elements receive Material styles.) 
however this error happens only on one specific array and the rest of arrays are working as expected. here is an image to showcase the issue:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue what I did was:

```
this.getEducations.push(this.fb.array([ this.fb.group({...}])
```

but the correct way was

```
this.getEducations.push(this.fb.group({...})
```

basically new item for the array should have been a group not another array